# How to hide Title Bar in Wix Installer?

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.7

[image]

I want to hide the title bar of the dialog in a msi installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Windows Installer supports that (though someone might have a clever way).

> The number of dialog style bits in Windows Installer is a reduced and specialized set.

--[Dialog Box Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Instead, you could bundle your MSI with a WiX Bootstrapper and write your own Bootstrapper Application to present whatever UI you wish. Unless you select otherwise, the UI in MSIs are not shown by the bootstrapper.

The WiX installer itself is a good example of a frameless window. You can consult the [source code](http://wix.codeplex.com/downloads/get/582222) for that.